# cmd: java <class> error

Tags: java, netbeans, command-line, jar

So I know there is a lot of information about this but I have been looking for my solution and not any places seem to have it.I have opened a separate folder having all my src and class files and CD'd my way from command prompt to there run:

```
  javac Filename.java
```

Compiles perfectly and gives me 6 class files: Filename$1.class through Filename$5.class and then Filename.class. I run

```
  java Filename
```

and I get:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
 Filename <wrong name :calcu/Filename>
```

folder that Filename is under.

my javac version is 1.7.0_21.

I am new to the programming world so please be understanding.

Comment: is Filename.java under package `calcu` ?

Comment: yes, that is the package/folder it is under

Comment: Can you see the `Filename.class` in the folder after you have compiled it. Try by running `dir Filename.class`

Comment: "Volume in Drive C is OS  Volume Serial Number is BCC1-80CE Directory of C:\Users...calcu  07/24/2013 10:21PM 6,216 Filename.class" I can see it there, it just will not find it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to create a JframeForm in netbeans so the main class it was searching for could not be found : (JFrameForm)

Answer (score 0):

may be class name and file name are different.

```
c:/>javac FileName.java
```

compiles and creates className.class
Now,

```
c:/>java ClassName
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I can see the class name it created in my folder. I just cannot run it with command prompt.

Comment: I even created a .jar but it doesn't run the same way my Filename.java does in Netbeans. All that appears is a cmd that flashes no "main" found.

Comment: @Potatoesforfish does your java program have a package ?

Comment: the package name is called "calcu" according to Netbeans IDE

Comment: if you are compiling through command prompt cmd>javac -d .(dot) FileName.java

Comment: now I have a folder on top of my original folder with all my classes src/calcu/calcu. although I have my same classes in src/calcu...

Comment: If you are using NetBeans --> Right Click on Java File -->Run as -->Java Application, then see the result

Comment: Runs perfectly. I originally set the project as a java application so I just hit run. because when you right click all there is is "run" for running.

Comment: @Potatoesforfish  It is not good to use IDE(Eclipse,NetBeans...etc) If you are in learning stage.

Comment: Well, I am sorry. But I did. It set up my GUI perfectly! And for two years I have been working on this project.

Answer (score 0):

Goto src folder (where is calcu) and execute:

```
javac calcu/Filename.java
```

For execute

```
java calcu.Filename
```

Comment: It says the file is not found, but when I go there I can see the file and directory shows it, here is the error message:

Comment: javac: file not found: calcu\Filename.java

Answer (score 0):

You must direct exactly src:

```
javac ../folderParent/Filename.java
```

and:

```
java ../folderParent/Filename
```

if you don't want to do that, you must go to that folder by using cd command!

Comment: I went exactly there through the cd command, to where I can dir to my filename.java and then I ran javac filename.java

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
java -cp . Filename
```

I found the following link that talks about this problem and suggests to use `-cp`...

[**Cannot Find Class File....**](http://www.coderanch.com/t/409650/java/java/Find-Class-File)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hmm. Can you try `java -version` and see if gives you the correct output? Just to make sure the classpath is set properly.